# How to print a confidence interval into a sentence in r by writing my own function

Tags: r

I'm trying to print a confidence interval into the same sentence.

Comment: You never get to the `print` statement, because you `return` from function `myColModel` in the line before. So swapping the last two lines in your function should do the job.

Comment: Thanks @MauritsEvers. That did one trick, but in my sentence for confint(y), how do I only get the colName 95% confidence interval instead of both the Intercept and the colName confidence interval?

Comment: Assuming `colName` is the name of a single predictor, does `confint(y)[rownames(confint(y)) == colName, ]` work?

Comment: @MauritsEvers I tried confint(y, parm = "nepalData[, colName]") and it worked. However, when I run the code, the lower and the upper confidence intervals come out in 2 separate sentences. Is there a way to get both confidence interval in 1 sentence?

Comment: @MauritsEvers for example: [1] "The 95% confidence interval for covariate  death is 598.476914988037 which means that we reject or fail to reject the null hypothesis that the coefficient of this covariate is zero "
[2] "The 95% confidence interval for covariate  death is 618.386893166022 which means that we reject or fail to reject the null hypothesis that the coefficient of this covariate is zero "

Comment: Please see my example solution below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `sprintf` or `paste0` to concatenate (and format) the lower and upper confidence value. Here is an example using `sprintf`.

```
# Sample data
y <- glm(mpg ~ wt, data = mtcars);
colName <- "wt";

# Print statement
print(paste0(
    "The 95% confidence interval for covariate  ",
    colName,
    " is ",
    sprintf("[ %4.3f, %4.3f ]", confint(y, parm = colName)[1], confint(y, parm = colName)[2]),
    " which means that we reject or fail to reject the null hypothesis that the coefficient of this covariate is zero "));
#[1] "The 95% confidence interval for covariate  wt is [ -6.440, -4.249 ] which means that we reject or fail to reject the null hypothesis that the coefficient of this covariate is zero "
```